InvalidEntryPoint error for AWS Lambda Serverless on provided.al2023 runtime
I'm trying to setup a Serverless lambda function using Go (provided.al2023) but I get an InvalidEntryPoint error:
Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap] Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
My project is structured like below:
backend/
-.bin/
--bootstrap
--bootstrap.zip
-go.mod
-go.sum
-main.go
frontend/
Makefile
serverless.yml

My serverless.yaml is as below:
service: my-service
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: provided.al2023
  architecture: arm64
  region: ap-southeast-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  httpApi:
    cors: true
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-go
package:
  patterns:
    - "!*/**"
    - backend/.bin/bootstrap
functions:
  healthcheck:
    handler: main.go
    events:
    - http:
      path: /healthcheck
      method: GET

According to the troubleshooting guide "This error typically occurs when the root of your deployment package doesn't contain an executable file named bootstrap. For example, if you're deploying a provided.al2023 function with a .zip file, the bootstrap file must be at the root of the .zip file, not in a directory."
This is my Makefile, what I am running when deploying the lambda:
back_sls_build:
  @cd backend && env GOARCH=arm64 GOOS=linux go build -tags lambda.norpc -o ./.bin/bootstrap main.go && cd ..
  @cd backend/.bin && zip -FS bootstrap.zip bootstrap && cd ../..

back_deploy: back_sls_build
  @serverless deploy --stage dev

I believe that the issue may have to do with the paths I've defined either for my handler, or the patterns in the serverless.yml file, but I've tried most combinations and can't seem to get it to work. Are the file paths in the yaml supposed to be relative to itself, or the bootstrap, or something else entirely?
